# How can I include a header from another project using cmake

Tags: c, cmake, mqtt, paho

I've been trying to add a header file from another project, more specifically MQTTClient.h from Paho MQTT.

Currently the project looks like this:

- src/

  - main.c
  - CMakeLists.txt
- inc/

  - paho.mqtt.c-master/

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - src/

      - MQTTClient.h
      - CMakeLists.txt

Currently my CMakeList.txt goes like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

project(market_listener)


SET(MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master)

set(MQTT
        "${MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR}"
        "${MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR}/src/MQTTClient.h"
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR}/src)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MQTT_INCLUDE_DIR}/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master)


add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master)
add_executable(listener src/main.c)


install (TARGETS listener DESTINATION bin)
install (FILES "src/main.c" DESTINATION src)
```

It's an amalgamation of failed attempts so it looks weird, and I'm also very bad at it.

I can `cmake ..` it, but when I do `make` I get the following:

```
E:/Projekti/C/Test_1/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master/src/Socket.c: In function 'Socket_error':
E:/Projekti/C/Test_1/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master/src/Socket.c:104:6: warning: '_errno' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
  int errno;
```

[image]

and later on:

```
E:/Projekti/C/Test_1/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master/src/Base64.c: In function 'Base64_encode':
E:/Projekti/C/Test_1/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master/src/Base64.c:36:63: error: 'CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF' undeclared (first use in this function)
  if ( CryptBinaryToStringA( in, in_len, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64 | CRYPT_STRING_NOCRLF, out, &dw_out_len ) )

E:/Projekti/C/Test_1/inc/paho.mqtt.c-master/src/Base64.c:36:63: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

[image]

Link to the project I'm trying to take the header from:
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want to have an error message in the **textual** form, so it can be searched for words and can be googled. Please, fix that issue with your question post. Also, I don't see how the error logs are related with `MQTTClient.h` file, which you want to include.

Comment: Well, the goal is to add the header file, and that's what i do in main.c. However, upon building I get the following, the errors shown are from the external project, so I assume they are a result of my bad CMakeList.txt. I pressume i didn't build the project correctly. Also, I've added the error messages.

Comment: 1. Try to build the external project (`paho.mqtt.c`) as *standalone*. It could be the project itself cannot be built on your machine. 2. Create a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` which only adds external project with `add_subdirectory`. (`cmake_minimum_required` and `project` are still needed). Check that this works. 3. Then add all `include_directories`, required for your own project, **after** the `add_subdirectory` call, so additional include directories won't affect on the external project. Other your code (variables, `add_executable`, an so on) add **after** the `add_subdirectory` too.

Comment: 1) Install the other project.  2) use the installed project 3) profit